# Building CUDA-aware openMPI on Ubuntu 12.04 cannot find cuda.h

Tags: ubuntu, cuda, mpi

I am building openMPI 1.8.5 on Ubuntu 12.04 with CUDA 6.5 installed and tested with default samples. I intend to run it on a single node with following configuration:

Dell Precision T7400
Dual Xeon X5450
Nvidia GT730/Tesla C1060

The configure command issued was

```
    $ ./configure --prefix=/usr --with-cuda=/usr/local/cuda
```

In the generated config.log, it is clear the the configure script was not able to find cuda.h and cuda_runtime_api.h in /usr/loca/cuda/include, which do exist.

For cuda.h:

```
    configure:73774: checking cuda.h usability
    configure:73774: gcc -std=gnu99 -c -O3 -DNDEBUG    conftest.c >&5
    conftest.c:645:18: fatal error: cuda.h: No such file or directory
    compilation terminated.
    configure:73774: $? = 1
    configure: failed program was:
    | /* confdefs.h */
```

For cuda_runtime_api.h:

```
    configure:73857: checking cuda_runtime_api.h presence
    configure:73857: gcc -E   conftest.c
    conftest.c:612:30: fatal error: cuda_runtime_api.h: No such file or directory
    compilation terminated.
    configure:73857: $? = 1
    configure: failed program was:
    | /* confdefs.h */
```

I tried to change the path to version-specific directory, i.e. /usr/loca/cuda-6.5/cuda but same error was thrown.

I tried to proceed to install, and the ompi_info gave

```
    mca:mpi:base:param:mpi_built_with_cuda_support:value:false
```

Does anybody had similar experience that can help me out? Many thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure it's the source of your issues around not locating those header files, but CUDA-aware MPI [depends on GPUDirect](http://devblogs.nvidia.com/parallelforall/introduction-cuda-aware-mpi/). However, [GPUDirect is not supported on your Tesla C1060](http://devblogs.nvidia.com/parallelforall/introduction-cuda-aware-mpi/), and [GPUDirect RDMA is not supported on your GT730](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/gpudirect-rdma/index.html#abstract)  So I would suggest that the hardware configuration you have is not a very good starting point for this kind of investigation.

Comment: Thank you @Robert. However I am not trying to utilize GPUDirect to have both GPUs solving my problem simultaneously. I simply want any one of them to work along side with 2 CPUs through openMPI. Am I having a wrong expectation?

Comment: CUDA aware MPI might possibly have some benefit in a single GPU case only if you were running multiple MPI ranks on a single GPU and were also using [CUDA MPS](https://docs.nvidia.com/deploy/pdf/CUDA_Multi_Process_Service_Overview.pdf).  Other than that, it would have no benefit in the single GPU/single node case.  Given that CUDA MPS requires a cc3.5 or higher GPU, it certainly won't work with the C1060, and may not work with the GT730, depending on which exact GT730 you have.  I don't think the idea is a sensible one.  You're welcome to try anything you wish, of course.

Comment: What happens if you just do: `./configure --prefix=/usr --with-cuda` ?  Also, the `gcc` compile command in the configure script doesn't seem to be passing any include directories to the compilation, which means that the `cuda.h` file must be included by full path in the `confdefs`  It might help if you showed the full output after that `failed program was:` message.

Comment: Those are useful information, @RobertCrovella. I had been playing openMPI on a 32 core machine and it was like magic, making me thought adding single core GPU CUDA will also be like a breeze. `./configure --prefix=/usr --with-cuda` was my first try, which gave the same output. Here is the output [config.log](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2Zaqw3T7kymVllWUzJSa1R1MDQ/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: I'm not sure the configure issue is an actual problem.  I downloaded ompi 1.8.5 and tried building it.   I observe the things you pointed out, but 1. If you look in your config.log for "checking if have cuda support" I think you'll find the next line says "result: yes"  2. If I give configure a bogus directory like `./configure --with-cuda=/home/foo` I will get a very obvious error message from configure, which I assume you are not getting.  Regarding the install problem, what command are you using exactly to make and install?

Comment: That was a nice counter-checking. The configure does throw an obvious error and stopped. I had tried ./configure --prefix=/usr --with-cuda, and variations by giving it paths, i.e. /usr/local/cuda, /usr/local/cuda-6.5/cuda. I also tried to give it explicit lib path by adding --with-cuda-libdir=/usr/local/cuda-6.5/lib with does not seem relevant to the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I think I fixed the problem. The conftest.c seems to be looking for cuda.h in /usr/include, instead of the supposed /usr/local/cuda/include. The problem is solved once I created a soft link of cuda.h and cuda_runtime_api.h.